# How do I make a specific part of my website look like this? (Using HTML and CSS.)

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm currently attempting to build a basic website using HTML, CSS and Javascript. However there's a specific part of this website that I'm having difficulty building. [Here's what the section is meant to look like, with the part on the left being the part that's tripping me up the most.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YleV.png) It's a section which is meant to contain four basic squares next to each other; Image 1 (linked earlier) provides a visual.

Here's an image of what I've currently managed to get: [All four squares are present, but they're stacked on top of one another instead.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF5gz.png) I haven't been able to get much closer to it.

Here's the html code behind it:

```
   <div class="top-large-left">
                        <h3 id="hot">Interaction</h3>                     
                    </div>                   
                    <div class="small-top-right">
                        <h3 id="item">Location</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="large-left-section">
                        <div>
                            <section class="left-section">
                                <div class="btn-group button">
                                    <div class="button1">
                                <button type="button1">Display X, Y</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="button2">
                                <button type="button2">Theme</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="button3">
                                <button type="button3">Modal</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="button4">
                                <button type="button4">Swap Image</button>
                            </div>
                                

                            </section>
                        </div>
```

As well as the CSS:

```
 .btn-group button {
    background-color: #428bca;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    padding: 32px 19px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2px 2px;
    border: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 25px;
  }
  .button1 {
    width: 130px;
  }  
  .button2 {
    width: 130px;
    
  }
  .button3 {
    width: 130px;
  }
  .button4 {
    width: 130px;
  }
```

**How would I be able to achieve what is being shown in the first image? Is the css-grid function what I need to use, or something else?** Feel free to say if I need to provide any more information, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Flex is your solution here. Flex makes your life easier.

> Run the snippet on full window. (Full page)

```css
 .top-large-left {
    background-color: #428bca;
    padding: 0 1rem;
 }
  .top-large-left h3 {
    margin:0;
  }
 .wrapper {
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:row;
 }
 .large-left-section,
 .large-right-section{
    flex: 1 1 50%;
    border: 10px solid lightgrey;
    text-align: center;
    margin:5px; 
}
 .btn-group button {
    background-color: #428bca;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    padding: 32px 19px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2px 2px;
    border: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 25px;
  }
.large-left-section .left-section .btn-group.button{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.large-left-section .left-section .btn-group.button .btn {
    flex: 0 0 45%;
    margin:5px;
}
.large-left-section .left-section .btn-group.button .btn button {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-large-left">
  <h3 id="hot">Interaction</h3>                     
</div> 
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="large-left-section">
    <section class="left-section">
        <div class="btn-group button">
           <div class="btn button1">
            <button type="button1">Display X, Y</button>
          </div>
          <div class="btn button2">
            <button type="button2">Theme</button>
          </div>
          <div class="btn button3">
            <button type="button3">Modal</button>
          </div>
          <div class="btn button4">
            <button type="button4">Swap Image</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="large-right-section">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would recommend to use css-grid for such task over flexbox. It does not have the issue of neededing to run at fulls creen to work. If you want a table like layout like in this case then css-grid is the betetr tool as you can control width and height at the same time.